# multiple definition error while compiling tftp-hpa

Tags: c, compiler-errors, tftp, multiple-definition-error

I wanna compiling [tftp-hpa from source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/tftp/tftp-hpa.git) but i get following error:

```
gcc  tftp.o main.o ../common/libcommon.a -lreadline -ltermcap  /home/ali/programming/c/opensource/tftp-hpa/lib/libxtra.a  -o tftp
/usr/bin/ld: main.o:/home/ali/programming/c/opensource/tftp-hpa/tftp/main.c:98: multiple definition of `toplevel'; tftp.o:/home/ali/programming/c/opensource/tftp-hpa/tftp/tftp.c:51: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:12: tftp] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ali/programming/c/opensource/tftp-hpa/tftp'
make: *** [Makefile:7: tftp.build] Error 2
```

And many warnings.

I tried to compile several source code from several resources like :

[Linux.org](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/tftp/tftp-hpa.git)

[here](https://github.com/Distrotech/tftp-hpa.git)

[Debian](https://salsa.debian.org/ron/tftp-hpa.git)

[here](https://github.com/asciiprod/tftp-hpa.git)

But every source code throw this compile error. Why ?

All of my commands for compiling `tftp` :

```
autoreconf -i

./configure

make
```

And error ...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed its source code on [this](https://github.com/alirezaarzehgar/tftp-hpa.git) repository based on [this](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/network/tftp/tftp-hpa) source code.

In this case we should remove `toplevel` variable from all .c files on tftp folder.

Write following line on `common/tftpsubs.h`:

```
#ifndef _TOP_LEVEL_
#define _TOP_LEVEL_
static sigjmp_buf toplevel;
#endif
```